# How to insert random points with weight?

Tags: qgis, random

I have a polygon shp divided in 5 regions. I want to fill it with 1000 random points but not to be so random :). I want 300 points to fill one region 100 another...for the moment the one tough decision I think about is to cut the regions in separate shp files and then to insert the amount of random points I want. After that i can unite all the shp files in one which will have all the random points. Is there another quicker way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **Vector -> Research Tools -> Random Points** by using a field to put your "weights". For example, in my shapefile the field **n_points** has the number of random points for each feature:

[image]

Selecting "Use value from input field" (**n_points**):

[image]

Result is showing the "weights" for each feature:

[image]

Comment: Oh I feel so ashamed,it was so simple? I didn't even tried to see what the last option does, thank you very much!